# Kubernetes deployment rolling update with semantic container names

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to use a Kubernetes [deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment) and reference container images with semantic tag names. E.g. `application:latest`, `application:testing`, `application:production`.

Setting this up is straight forward and with the `imagePullPolicy: Always` within my container spec I can also push out new versions quickly with something like this:

```
 $ REPLICAS=$(kubectl get deployment application --template="{{.spec.replicas}}")
 $ kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment application
 deployment "application" scaled
 $ kubectl scale --replicas=$REPLICAS deployment application
 deployment "application" scaled
```

The drawback is that all pods are killed before the new ones are ready. Therefore I'm looking to get rolling updates going.

One solution would be to drop the semantic tag names and use sth. like `application:v123`. But I'd love to keep my scripts simple and keep the semantic names. Is there any way to do that?

...

Edit/update ... this is what my `deployment.yaml` configuration would look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: nginx-deployment
 spec:
   replicas: 3
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: application
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: application
         image: application:latest
         imagePullPolicy: Always
```

It would basically stay the same all the time, but the related container image is updated in the background.

...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this isn't possible using one semantic tag. Here's what I started using with two or more tags.

1) Figure our what's currently deployed:

```
 DEPLOYED_IMAGE=$(kubectl get deployment/nginx-deployment -o jsonpath="{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image}")
```

2) Find the unused tag:

```
if [[ "$DEPLOYED_IMAGE" =~ :green$ ]]; then 
   IMAGE="application:latest-blue"
else 
   IMAGE="application:latest-green"
fi
```

3) Build the image with the new tag:

```
docker build -t $IMAGE .
docker push $IMAGE
```

4) Deploy

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment application=$IMAGE
```

5) Wait until the deployment is done

```
kubectl rollout status deployment nginx-deployment -w
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, probably I misunderstood the question, but why don't you use

> kubectl apply -f

(Ref [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_apply/))

Then you can decide the speed of your deployment setting

- maxSurge
- maxUnavailable

in your deployment file. (ref [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#rolling-update-deployment))

Comment: due to the fact that the actual deployment configuration would not change, the `kubectl apply -f` does not find any difference and therefore it does not start the rolling update